# Circular bitmap with Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, android-bitmap

We are showing a notification with a large icon get from an URL. So, in order to load the image we are using Universal Image Loader with the following code:

```
mImageLoader.loadImage(imagePath, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(loadedImage);
            notificationManager.notify(notification.getId(), notificationBuilder.build());
        }
});
```

This code is working fine and the image is successfully shown. Our problem is that we want to show a circular large icon, so we need the bitmap to be circular. We have tried by setting:

```
    final DisplayImageOptions imageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(1000))
            .build();
```

But this is not working, we've tried with RoundedBitmapDrawable, but we need a bitmap and not a bitmapdrawable. 
Please, how could we do in order to get a circular bitmap?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of use CircleImageView https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView or https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. We do not want to display the circle image in an image view, we want to set it as large icon in a notification, so it has to be a bitmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 public static Bitmap getCircularBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output;

    if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    } else {
        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    float r = 0;

    if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
        r = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
    } else {
        r = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
    }

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We have already tried it but its not working, we need a circular bitmap, and this is transforming the imageview to circular, not the bitmap

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much, the code is working fine. Thank you so much! However, do you know if there's a way of doing the same but with Universal Image Loader? Do you think this is a good solution (as this is creating a new bitmap, so it could generate out of memory problems)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the option `.displayer(new CircleBitmapDisplayer())` ? For example:

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
 .displayer(new CircleBitmapDisplayer())
 .build();
```